# Is it possible to get the raw IR image data from the Superframe?

Tags: google-project-tango

I am using the java API with the Tango Peanut phone, and I wanted to know if there is a way to get the raw IR image from the RGB-IR camera that the depth sensor uses.  I know that a quarter of the pixels from the RGB-IR camera is IR data.  I also know that all of the 4MP RGB-IR image gets put into the superframe and then converted to YUV. However it was unclear on how to decode the IR channel, or if it is even possible at this point.  If its lost inside the YUV superframe, is there any other way I can retrieve the raw IR image?

Comment: How do you know that IR sensitive data can be extracted from YUV raw frame? By IR sensitive channel, I mean a one channel image that can see emitted IR pattern (not the Depth channel).

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the depth data:

1. http://www.pocketmagic.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sbrl.zip
   taken from http://palcu.blogspot.ro/2014/04/google-project-tango-hackathon-in.html

You might also wanna try

2. https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/wiki/Depth:-Point-Cloud-Viewer
3. http://www.pocketmagic.net/2014/05/google-tango-hackathon-in-timisoara/#.VCQ6H1eHuiN

Please keep me posted on success/failure. Are you on a tablet or phone?

Comment: according to a someone at google tango, their API doesn't support a way of getting RAW IR image